# do you need to explicitly bind a function?

Tags: reactjs

I have a function called multiply and a component called NumberInputField when I pass the function to the component I use:

```
<NumberInputField id='1' action={this.multiply} />
```

but I also have seen:

```
<NumberInputField id='1' action={this.multiply.bind(this)} />
```

they both seem to work. Is there a difference? Is one way more acceptable?

Comment: Does the function use `this`? How is the function defined? What react version are you using? All that information will affect the answer.

Comment: If the answer helped, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: Without showing the code for `this.multiply`, it's hard to know which part you're not understanding

Comment: thanks, as the function is written I don't need to bind the action to this @underwood cleared up the problem with his answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you `bind` a function, you're giving that function context of the class you're currently in. If, for example, the `multiply()` function needed to use `this.setState()` then you would need to use `bind` so that the function has the appropriate context.

However, it is not a good idea to use `bind` in your render method. Why? Because each time `render` is called, the `bind` will occur again. Instead you can bind the function in your constructor

e.g.

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.multiply = this.multiply.bind(this);
}
```

even better, if you use babel's transform class properties plugin, you can write your functions like so

```
export default class App extends Component {

    multiply = () => {
       //Automatically knows about "this"
    };

}
```

While some answers do note that you only need it if you should access "this" in that function. It is important you understand the best practices as well. Do **not** bind in the render method.

Answer (score 1):

Edited:

It depends on what the function is doing.  If you need access to state, props, etc. then yes you need to bind it. Best practice is to create it as an arrow function or bind it in the constructor.

If not, then no. But, best practice would be to move that function to a helper file so it can be used again in the future if it is a function that is reusable.